# Multiple @GetMapping servlets with same path?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, thymeleaf

I want to create multiple servlets to the `/persons` path. The path without any query parameters should just serve the html page (using `Thymeleaf` templating).

The one with parameters should instead populate the http model with data.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/persons")
public class PricingCacheController {

    //default just routing to the html template
    @GetMapping(params = "")
    public String personsHtml() {
        System.out.println("initial page load");
        return "persons";
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String personsGet(Model model, @RequestParam MyBean bean) {
        System.out.println("get request");
        model.addAttribute("dto", dao.findAll());
        return "persons";
    }
```

When executing `localhost:8080/persons`, I get a `404` not found.

Comment: probably it would be much easier if you would refer to [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping) for request mapping types. You can use `@PathVariable` and `@RequestMethod` annotation to distinguish HTTP Methods

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this, servlet mapping is done on the url level and query parameters are ignored when parsing the url so since you have to mappings for the same path (regardless the query parameters) you will get 404, why not use path variables?